# Unwrap lines after increasing line length in code style

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-formatting

In a Java project that I'm working on with IntelliJ, we increased the allowed line length in the code style.

IntelliJ happily wraps lines that are *longer* than allowed by code style when auto-formatting. However, I would like to do the opposite: unwrap multiple lines that are way *shorter* than allowed.

Is there a way to clear unnecessary line breaks when auto-formatting with IntelliJ?

Comment: Please try to disable "Keep when reformatting - Line Breaks" in "File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | Java".

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is a workaround for sure, but you can:

- Select the full file with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
- Join all lines with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>
- Reformat file with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: This messes up vertical whitespace, but it's an original approach :)